# which graph database to use

Tags: nosql, graph-databases

Are there any open-source graph-databases around which are able to store binary data, scale horizontally and optionally provide versioning of stored data?

I am overwhelmed by the sheer amount of dbs out there, but none of them seems to have all the desired features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary storage, horizontal scale, and versioning requirements all sound like good candidates for a BigTable model like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) or [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/).  If you really need a graph database, those may not be a good fit, however.  If you can expand a bit more on what the requirements are, we could make a better suggestion.

Comment: We are looking for a filesystem in which nodes are linked via traditional parent-child relationships but may also have links(edges) to other nodes containing different semantic info.
Right now this is done via Subversion (which handles binary storage, horizontal scale, and versioning perfectly) but as it resembles a traditional filesystem we cannot add multiple links pointing to other files.

Comment: You might try http://neo4j.org, for some domain examples, look at http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Domain_Modeling_Gallery or http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/

Answer (score 7):

Look at [OrientDB](https://orientdb.com/): open source (Apache 2 license), very fast. Supports SQL and graph GREMLIN language.

Answer (score 1):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL][1]

for example:

> InfiniteGraph - High-performance, scalable, distributed Graph Database

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal scaling, look at Titan (uses Cassandra underneath): [Titan homepage](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/), [Titan presentation video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkAYA4Kd8JE)

For versioning your graph (if that's what you *really* need), you could try using [Antiquity](https://github.com/asaf/antiquity) on top of a graph store.

From the Titan site:

> Titan is a highly scalable graph database optimized for storing and querying massive-scale graphs containing hundreds of billions of vertices and edges distributed across a multi-machine cluster. Titan is a transactional database that can support thousands of concurrent users executing complex graph traversals.
>
> In addition, Titan provides the following features:
>
> - Elastic and linear scalability for a growing data and user base.
> - Data distribution and replication for performance and fault tolerance.
> - Multi-datacenter high availability and hot backups.
> - Support for ACID and eventual consistency.
> - Support for various storage backends:
>
>   - Apache Cassandra
>   - Apache HBase
>   - Oracle BerkeleyDB
> - Support for geo, numeric range, and full-text search via:
>
>   - ElasticSearch
>   - Apache Lucene
> - Native integration with the TinkerPop graph stack:
>
>   - Gremlin graph query language
>   - Frames object-to-graph mapper
>   - Rexster graph server
>   - Blueprints standard graph API
> - Open source with the liberal Apache 2 license.-